# How to call a function from another function

Tags: javascript

So I'm writing two functions, each is responsible for validating a textfield, one is for a phone number and the other name. I have both functions working, but Not sure how to call both of them from one button "calculate". I was wondering if I could somehow call the chkPH() function from my chkName() function, in its else statement. Like so:

```
function chkName()
  {

   if(not valid)
   {error}
   else { go to chkPH() function } 


  }
```

Comment: It should just be `else {chkPH();} ` according to your code.

Comment: Not you cannot do like 'go to chkPH() function'. Instead you should call just 'chkPH()'

Comment: it was pesudocode dude.

Comment: So what? A function can be called by its name followed by a pair of parentheses in which one or more arguments may present and a terminating semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call it same as from anywhere, by putting parentheses after its name:

```
function chkName() {
    var valid = ...;
    if (!valid) {
        ... error ...
    }
    else {
        chkPh();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you it worked! (not use to JScript just learning the syntax)